# Volatile boolean to prevent deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote this code to overcome the deadlock condition described in [this Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html).

**Summary of Problem:**

> Alphonse and Gary are friends, and great believers in courtesy. A strict rule of courtesy is that when you bow to a friend, you must remain bowed until your friend has a chance to return the bow. Unfortunately, this rule does not account for the possibility that two friends might bow to each other at the same time.

I used a volatile boolean `CanBow()` to check if either of the friends are bowing so that the condition when both of them bow and wait for the other to bow back will not happen.

Is this a valid way to handle deadlocks as opposed to using locks?

```
public class NewThread extends Thread {
    Friend bower;
    Friend bowBack;
    NewThread(Friend bower,Friend bowBack){
       this.bower = bower;
       this.bowBack = bowBack;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
       if(bowBack.canBow())
             bower.bow(bowBack);
    }
}

public class ApplicationThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        final Friend alphonse = new Friend("Alphonse");
        final Friend gary = new Friend("Gary");
        NewThread t1 = new NewThread(alphonse,gary);
        NewThread t2 = new NewThread(gary,alphonse);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
    static class Friend {
        private final String name;
        private volatile boolean canBow;
        public Friend(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            canBow = true;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
        public boolean canBow(){
            return canBow;
        }
        public synchronized void bow(Friend bower) {
                canBow = false;
                System.out.format("%s: %s"
                    + "  has bowed to me!%n", 
                    this.name, bower.getName());
                bower.bowBack(this);
                canBow = true;
        }
        public synchronized void bowBack(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s"
                + " has bowed back to me!%n",
                this.name, bower.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `NewClass` should be `NewThread` if I'm not missing something and your static class should have proper indentation.

Comment: Agreed and edited. Are there any known advantages of using locks over volatiles?

Comment: @SindhujaNarasimhan The only reason to use a volatile is if two or more threads will be accessing a field whose value will change. Volatile fields don't have any direct relationship to deadlocks. On the other hand, synchronized blocks and other monitor/lock objects are what you would use in order to prevent a deadlock (or other sorts of -lock). In general, you prevent a deadlock by making sure that only thread has access to a resource (such as a monitor) at any one time: you would do this by using a Lock object or a synchronized block.

Comment: There's a useful comparison of volatiles and synchronization here: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to the wonderful world of deadlocks. In a nutshell: No, your “solution” is not adequate. Here is some pseudocode detailing what the two threads are doing. Note that a `synchronized` method aquires a lock on the object it is called on.

```
THREAD 1                             |     THREAD 2                            
IF:                                  |     IF:                                 
synchronized (gary) {                |     synchronized (alphonse) {               
  // gary.canBow();                  |       // alphonse.canBow();                 
  gary.canBow;                       |       alphonse.canBow;                      
}                                    |     }                                   
THEN:                                |     THEN:                               
synchronized (alphonse) {            |     synchronized (gary) {           
  // alphonse.bow(gary);             |       // gary.bow(alphonse);            
  alphonse.canBow = false;           |       gary.canBow = false;          
  ...                                |       ...                               
  // gary.bowBack(alphonse)          |       // alphonse.bowBack(gary)         
  synchronized (gary) {              |       synchronized (alphonse) {             
    ...                              |         ...                             
  }                                  |       }                                 
  alphonse.canBow = true;            |       gary.canBow = true;           
}                                    |     }
```

We can see that `gary` and `alphonse` can be locked at the same time. Especially, the `bowBack.canBow()` can return `true` in both threads. Then, even when the `canBow` boolean is `volatile`, both objects can wait for each other in a deadlock (in Thread 1, `alphonse` is locked and waits for `gary`. In Thread 2, the other way round).

You can make this deadlock more likely by increasing the time between the `bowBack.canBow()` and `bower.bow()` calls:

```
public void run(){
   if(bowBack.canBow()) {
       Thread.sleep(100);  // exception handling omitted
       bower.bow(bowBack);
   }
}
```

To solve these issues, you could impose an order or hierarchy on the friends, so that locks are aquired in exactly the same order in all threads (e.g. always synchronize on `alphonse` before `gary`). You could also decide that only one friend may initiate a bow at any time, e.g. via a semaphore.

But your implementation doesn't work.